# In CS5 i get a loss of font effects when saving from psd to jpg. How to prevent that?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5

I save psd images and fonts to jpg for ease of printing on a computer that doesn't have psd ability.  How do I keep the font effects without losing them when I save to the jpg file?

Comment: What do you mean when you lose the font effect? When saving a PSD file to Jpg, you shouldn't lose any effects. Saving as a JPG will just flatten the document and compress the file. Are you referring to losing the ability to edit the file?

Answer (score 1):

Just flatten your image so you know exactly what layers are you really using and sending to print.

Use a copy for that, so you do not damage your original PSD.

Comment: Like @rafael said, I would duplicate all layers, then flatten them, so the flattened layer is above all layers below. Then export to JPG, delete the flattened top layer and save the PSD.

Answer (score -2):

Quick solution: Take a screen shot. The result is basically the same -- a raster image without layers.

Comment: Also, the OP's mention of "saving fonts" to JPEG suggests a misunderstanding of what JPEG format supports.